# Vectors and Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I am working on a project and for some reason when I run it and select option B it takes me back the menu and I am not sure why, it's not doing the case B process... Someone who can help me find my mistake? Thanks!

This is what I did:

```
package arreglosprincipal;

/**
 *
 * @author Thais Arelis
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProblemasArreglos {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int Arreglos [];
    String opcion=" ";
    public ProblemasArreglos(){
}
public void llenarArreglo(){
    String MenuPrincipal=("Seleccione lo que desea hacer: "
                         +"\n A- Ingresar Valores"
                         +"\n B- Imprimir"
                         +"\n C- Calcular el mayor"
                         +"\n D- Ordenar Valores"
                         +"\n E- Buscar Valor"
                         +"\n F- Salir");
   do{
   System.out.println(MenuPrincipal);
    opcion=sc.next();
      switch(opcion) {
      case "A":
      case "a":
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you wish to enter?");
    int cantidad;
    cantidad=sc.nextInt();
    Arreglos=new int[cantidad];
    for(int i=0;i<Arreglos.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Please write a number");
        Arreglos[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    for(int i=0;i<Arreglos.length;i++){
        System.out.println("The numbers are:"+ Arreglos[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    break;
    case "B":
    case "b":
        String Arreglos []= new String[5];
        String numero;
    for(int i=0;i<Arreglos.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Numero:");
        numero=sc.nextLine();
        Arreglos[i]=numero;      
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Arreglos.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Los numeros son:"+ Arreglos[i]);
    }
    break;
}
}while(opcion!="F");

}
}
```

Comment: Below case "b": you wrote "String Arreglos [] = new String[5]". Are you sure about that? Reading your code I think it should be "Arreglos=new int[5];"

Answer (score 1):

I ran these code in eclipse, then it ran normally except the cursor was not at the new line below `System.out.print`. Another phenomenon is that pressing "F" would not exit as expected.

In java, `Object == Object` compares the two references, not their values. You can use `char option`, which is one primitive data type, or use `option.euqals("F")` to avoid reference comparsion.